# Was Isaac aware that Jacob was fleeing Esau?

Tags: genesis, jacob, niv, isaac, esau

It seems only the mother was aware of the threat that Esau had issued

Genesis 27:42 NIV

> 42 When Rebekah was told what her older son Esau had said, she sent
> for her younger son Jacob and said to him, “Your brother Esau is
> planning to avenge himself by killing you.

Rebecca only mentions to Isaac how disgusting the canaanite women were and that she feared Jacob might end up marrying one of them

Genesis 27:46 NIV

> ”46 Then Rebekah said to Isaac, “I’m disgusted with living because of
> these Hittite women. If Jacob takes a wife from among the women of
> this land, from Hittite women like these, my life will not be worth
> living.”

Even when Isaac bids farewell to Jacob he only mentions the issue of the Canaanite womem

Genesis 28:1-2 NIV

> 1 So Isaac called for Jacob and blessed him. Then he commanded him: “Do
> not marry a Canaanite woman. 2 Go at once to Paddan Aram,[a] to the
> house of your mother’s father Bethuel. Take a wife for yourself there,
> from among the daughters of Laban, your mother’s brother

Was Isaac aware of Esau's threat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certain that not every conversation between these people has been recorded in the Bible.  Only a brief summary of the story is told with the important points.  However, the following is clear.

- Esau had already married at least two women who were not of Isaac's faith as recorded in the OP (Gen 27:46).
- Rebekah loved Jacob (more than she love Esau) and helped him to deceive Isaac over the birthright.
- Rebekah then raises the subject of Jacob's unmarried state in an effort to manipulate Isaac to send Jacob away (a long way away) to get a wife.  This was an excellent way to disguise the fact that Jacob had to flee his brother's murderous intentions.

I am sure than Isaac eventually found out what was going on, but when Jacob left for Paddam Aram, Isaac was unaware of the full story.